# How to use ionic4 manually>

Tags: ionic-framework, npm

I want to use ionic4 for my project;
 but, by installing ionic using npm, I get ionic 5 as default;

How can I get specific version of ionic using npm?

`npm install ionic`

Comment: Check here https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/start if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
npm install -g ionic@3.20.0
```

Or change it for the version you want like 3.0.0 if available.